# DateTime "ddd" format makes wrong output when on Android

Tags: c#, datetime, localization, xamarin.android, internationalization

I'm building a calendar type table with the abbreviated weekday name on the top.

*For the next examples, I'll use the following variable:*

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( 2017, 06, 22, 18, 00, 00 );
```

If I attempt to do `dateTime.ToString( "ddd" )`, it outputs `Thu` in both *C# Interactive* and Android. But if I do `dateTime.ToString( "ddd", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture( "pt-PT" ) )` instead, it outputs `qui` in *C# Interactive*, as expected, but `Quinta` in Android. Is this an error within Xamarin / Android, or am I missing something?

Comment: you can try to change Date​Time​Format​Info.​Abbreviated​Day​Names Property.
[How to change url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviateddaynames?view=netframework-4.7).

[More Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dddSpecifier)

Comment: It seems that, while on Android, the weekdays become a shorter version rather than the abbreviated version.